# Mean stack app not working well on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mean-stack

I have developed a SaaS app using MEAN that is working perfect on my local machines and server now I have deploy my app on AWS EC2 instance.

now I have problem with my server whenever I request with big data query my ec2 instance / server stop I cannot access it from putty or FileZilla.

Should I use other hosting service or there is my app infrastructure problem?

(sorry for bad English)

Comment: what do you mean by "request big data", is mongodb running on your EC2 or Atlas. By the way, look at the ram usage

Comment: yes mongodb running on EC2... (big data) I mean big query when I query on 1000s of records sometimes I got 504 Gateway error on response and after it I need to restart the instance and wait for some minutes for next request.

Comment: you should look at the mongodb logs then. You'll find the logs location in the configuration file for the server. Then grep for fatal errors: `<lookForFile> | grep s:"F" | tail` This will show you the last errors. I believe this could be related to `ulimit` and that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your EC2 instance is out of resources, hence not responding to the Putty/FileZilla apps.
You may check the CPU% on the monitoring tab in EC2 console, or via CloudWatch.
Also, You may install and configure CloudWatchAgent on your instance to get improved logging of RAM and also application logs.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html

If the problems is resources (CPU, RAM, Disk), You can change your instance type to a more appropriate one.

BTW, instead of using Putty/FileZilla, you can connect with you instance via the connect tab or session manager (see attached image). Right click on the instance name, and choose "connect". [image][image]